# How to filter SharePoint REST result?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-2013

I have two SharePoint lists Car Type(Parent) and Car Model (Child)

Car Type have two column
1) Car Type
2) Gear type (Auto, manual)

Car Model have Three columns
1) Car Type ( lookup to Car Type list --> Car Type Column )

2) Number
3) Car model

[Car Model list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQhLo.jpg)

```
function createCartable (){          
$("# createCartable").click(function(){   
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('car model')/items?$Select= Car_x0020_Type/Title, Car_x0020_model, Number &$expand= Car_x0020_Type"; 

$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {                                                                                           
         "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
         "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
   },
   success: onSuccess,
   error: function (error) {                                                                                             
         console.log(JSON.stringify(error));                                                                              
          }
   });

 var Type = "";
 var MaxSpeed = "";

 // Second Call to Car type
 function onSuccessIncident(data){
       Type = data.d.results[0].Type;
       dataStarted = data.d.results[0]. Max_x0020_Speed;                                        
 };

  function onSuccess(data) {                                                                                                          
      for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {                                                                                                
          var items = data.d.results[i];                      

var requestUriTwo = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(Car Type')/items?$Filter=Title eq '" + items. Car_x0020_Type.Title.toString() + "' $Select= Car_x0020_Type, Gear_x0020_type";

$.ajax({                                                                                                                              
   url: requestUriTwo,                                                                                                                               
   async: false,                                                                                                                               
   type: "GET",                                                                                                                              
   headers: {                                                                                                                                                           
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",                                                                                                                                                             
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"                                                                                                                             
 },                                                                                                                          
 success: onSuccessIncident,                                                                                                                               
   error: function (error) {                                                                                                                                             
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));                                                                                                                               
 }                                                                                                            
});                                                          

//JavaScript Table Code that auto populates goes here                  
   };
  }             
 });
};
```

The result and the question is inside the image

[Result and Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXTGU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sample demo(use underscore library for grouping data).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#createCartable").click(function () {
                var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('car model')/items?$Select= Car_x0020_Type/Title, Car_x0020_model, Number &$expand= Car_x0020_Type";

                $.ajax({
                    url: requestUri,
                    async: false,
                    type: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    },
                    success: onSuccess,
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                    }
                })

                var Type = "";
                var MaxSpeed = "";

                // Second Call to Car type
                function onSuccessIncident(data) {
                    Type = data.d.results[0].Type;
                    dataStarted = data.d.results[0].Max_x0020_Speed;
                }

                function onSuccess(data) {
                    var _Results = data.d.results;
                    var grouped = _.groupBy(_Results, function (item) {
                        return item.Car_x0020_Type.Title
                    })
                    _.each(grouped, function (v, k) {
                        var maxItem = _.max(v, function (item) { return item.Number; });
                        var requestUriTwo = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Car Type')/items?$filter=Title eq '" + maxItem.Car_x0020_Type.Title.toString() + "'&$Select=Title,Gear_x0020_type";

                        $.ajax({
                            url: requestUriTwo,
                            async: false,
                            type: "GET",
                            headers: {
                                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                var typeItem = data.d.results[0];
                                if (typeItem.Gear_x0020_type === "Auto")
                                    $('#table_id > tbody').append('<tr><td>' + typeItem.Title + '</td><td>' + maxItem.Car_x0020_model + '</td><td>' + maxItem.Number + '</td><td style="background-color:green">' + typeItem.Gear_x0020_type + '</td></tr>');
                                else
                                    $('#table_id > tbody').append('<tr><td>' + typeItem.Title + '</td><td>' + maxItem.Car_x0020_model + '</td><td>' + maxItem.Number + '</td><td style="background-color:red">' + typeItem.Gear_x0020_type + '</td></tr>');
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                            }
                        })
                    })

                    //for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                    //    var items = data.d.results[i];
                    //}
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
    <input id="createCartable" type="button" value="createCartable" />
    <table id="table_id" class="display" style="text-align:center;border:1px solid" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Car Model</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Gear Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

[image]